# How to dynamically add or remove form fields?

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamicform

I have the following `form`:

```
<table>            
    <tr id="type">
        <td><label >Type</label></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="1">Audio</option>
                <option value="2">Video</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="name">
       <td><label>Name</label></td>
       <td><input  type="text" name="name"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="form_fields">
        <td><label>comments</label></td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>       

     <tr>
         <td><input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add More"></td>
         <td><input type="button" id="removeButton" value="Remove"></td> 
         <td><input type="button" id="resetButton" value="Reset"></td> 
     </tr>      

     <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to add some of above table rows **dynamically** like this:

```
<div class="addThis">
    <tr id="type">
        <td><label >Type</label></td>
        <td>
            <select><option value="1">Audio</option>
            <option value="2">Video</option></select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="name">
        <td><label>Name</label></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="name"></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE

My requirement is,some of above fields like select, input tag should be added when I click on add button.

1) Add button: on click of add button select and input tag should be added.

2) Remove button: and on click of remove button. If above tags are added then they must be removed.

To achieve this I tried something in jQuery, but I could not do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 5 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }   

        var newText = $('.addThis');
        newTextBox.appendTo("#form_fields");

        counter++;
  });


  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
      if (counter == 1) {
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
      }   

      counter--;

      $('addThis').remove();
  });

});
```

Can anyone do give the demo on this?

Comment: Tip: You can use `.length` instead of keeping a global `counter` variable to check the number of fields.

Comment: If you check your console, there's an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: newTextBox is not defined`.

Comment: avoid using same id for all <tr>...use class instead of id

Comment: Actually you shouldn't just avoid using the same id for multiple elements. You shouldn't even think about doing this, because it's totally invalid.

Comment: There's no element with id `TextBoxesGroup`, so you're trying to add nothing (undeclared `newTextBox`) to nothing.

Comment: There's no element with id starting with `TextBoxDiv` to be removed, so the remove won't work either.

Comment: In brief, your code shouldn't work at all as it is. Please review it and edit your question if some real problem occurs.

Comment: @melanciauk,ok I will update this question

Comment: You can't put a div directly inside a table but Putting a div inside a td or th element is fine,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're a bit lost here, even after updating your question. This code should work, but I'm just ASSUMING your page should look like this.

I've replaced useless IDs with CLASSES, so you avoid ID duplication, but of course you can work around it and put back the IDs if necessary.

**HTML**

```
<table id="TextBoxesGroup">
    <tr class="type">
        <td>
            <label>Type</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="1">Audio</option>
                <option value="2">Video</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="name">
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="comments">
        <td>
            <label>comments</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea rows="2" cols="2"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add More" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="removeButton" value="Remove" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="resetButton" value="Reset" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$(function () { // Short way for document ready.
    $("#addButton").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".type").length > 10) { // Number of boxes.
            alert("Only 5 textboxes allow");

            return false;
        }

        var newType = $(".type").first().clone().addClass("newAdded"); // Clone the group and add a new class.
        var newName = $(".name").first().clone().addClass("newAdded"); // Clone the group and add a new class.

        newType.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup"); // Append the new group.
        newName.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup"); // Append the new group.
    });

    $("#removeButton").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".type").length == 1) { // Number of boxes.
            alert("No more textbox to remove");

            return false;
        }

        $(".type").last().remove(); // Remove the last group.
        $(".name").last().remove(); // Remove the last group.
    });

    $("#resetButton").on("click", function () {
        $(".newAdded").remove(); // Remove all newly added groups.
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Prb/2/)

Comment: No problems. From this point you can work around any changes you need.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?
Each row has a unique id, but all rows have the same class `.cont`.
This is pretty much it. Have fun!

### [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/cg3fL/3/)

```
var idnum = 0;
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#addButton').click( function () {
        $(document.body).append(
            "<div class='cont' id='row" + idnum + "'>" +
            "    <tr>" +
            "        <td><label>Type</label></td>" +
            "        <td>" +
            "            <select>" +
            "                <option value='1'>Audio</option>" +
            "                <option value='2'>Video</option>" +
            "            </select>" +
            "        </td>" +
            "    </tr>" +
            "    <tr id='name'>" +
            "        <td><label>Name</label></td>" +
            "        <td><input type='text' name='name'></td>" +
            "    </tr>" +
            "</div>"
        );

        idnum++;
    });

    $('#resetButton').click( function () {
        $('.cont').remove();
    });

    $('#removeButton').click(function() {
        var rowName = '#row' + idnum;
        $(rowName).remove();
        idnum--;
    });

});
```